# How to use d-i and preseeding on 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to set up an automated installation environment for ubuntu 22.04. We have this already working in production for 20.04 and previous LTS releases for many years. We use pxe/isolinux and a tftp and dhcp server to perform the network and cd boot. And some trickery to get uefi working.

I am unable to find working vmlinuz and initrd images which allow me to start an automated ubuntu 22.04 installation using preseeding and the debian installer (d-i).

I use the following to install 20.04, this does not work on 22.04:

```
linuxefi /path/to/2004/amd64/linux auto=true priority=critical url=http://example.com/ubuntu/2004/amd64/seed_ub_uefi.cfg console-setup/layoutcode=us interface=auto
initrdefi /path/to/2004/amd64/initrd.gz
```

I have tried extracting the vmlinuz and initrd.gz images from 22.04 ubuntu CD iso images. However no matter what I try it even fails to find a root filesystem. I am guessing the images do not have d-i and preseed functionality built in anymore?

If such images don't exist how would I go about creating my own? I don't feel too happy migrating to whatever automated installation method canonical wants to enforce. Our whole infrastructure is based on the previously mentioned method and we install multiple OSes in a similar way.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu already switched to cloud-init in 20.04, they only kept the preseed method for compatibility. Now it's gone for good.

You need to create a .yml file with the filename `user-data`, as [specified here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference).

Then you can provide the path to the directory containing the file in grub.cfg.

I provide the file directly on the .iso (in the directory `/nocloud/`), but you can just as easily provide a http location.

```
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server (autoinstall)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz   quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud/ ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

Comment: a pretty well made file format - but why on earth did we need another one to implement everywhere... especially since of course the documentation still has gaps (lv sizes/names/mount options?). anyone needing to implement a modest security baseline will have to guess around again. like with preseed, like with kickstart, like with autoyast (yes, ubuntu's kickstart was never finished but would have been a great step forward)...

Answer (score 3):

Preceeding has been deprecated since 20.04 and was removed in 22.04. Ubuntu is now using autoinstall (also called cloud-init): https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

If you need an elaborate working example, take a look at this GitHub repo: https://github.com/lavabit/robox

It uses Packer to generate Vagrant boxes for multiple providers. It has been using autoinstall since Ubuntu 20.10.